# VBA reference taken from a sheet stored in array used for cell selection in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In a sheet I have stored references to cells addresses in column C and formulas in column B and sheet name in column A. I have found a way to trim the formulas, now I would like to use the cell addresses in column C to replace the formula I have trimmed in column B in different sheets in addresses given,using the sheet reference names given in column A. So if A1 says sheet Austria, B1 has formula Sum(A1:D1), C1 has cell reference A345, I would like to be able to paste B1 in A345 in sheet Austria.

Here is the code, it stops at using cell reference to refer to the cells in a specific sheet. for some reason VBA doesn't like the fact that I am doing it this way. I have been researching and since I am a beginner, I am not sure how to do it. Your help would be appreciated. I would appreciate if you could make changes to the code when trying to explain.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim puff As String
Dim puff1 As String
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Dim strjn As String
Dim Rng As Range


With Columns("C:C")
 .Replace What:="[Lisbon.xlsx.xlsm]", Replacement:=""
End With

With Columns("C:C")
 .Replace What:="'='", Replacement:="='"
End With

With Columns("B:B")
 .Replace What:="$", Replacement:=""
End With

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Linkslist")
n = sh.Range("C2", sh.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("B2:B" & n).Value)

For i = 2 To n
j = i - 1
Worksheets("LinksList").Activate
puff = Chr(34) & arr(j) & Chr(34)
Range("C" & i).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(Range("A" & i).Value).Select
Range(Range(puff)).Select
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Linkslist")
n = sh.Range("C2", sh.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = 2 To n
    Worksheets(sh.Range("A" & i)).Range(sh.Range("C" & i)).Formula = "=" & sh.Range("B" & i)
Nexti
```

Comment: Your answer is good but it would be better if you explain why and how

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply.this is giving me type mismatch error.

Comment: This is the data I have on Sheet linkslist:  
Worksheet Cell        Formula 
Austria       AY186       ='Yearly inputs'!puff